# "No child processes" error in perl

Tags: perl, unix, sql-loader

I have a Perl script which invokes the sqlldr and loads data to a table from a flat file.

Now, my problem is, even though the sqlldr loads the table fine it is returning exit code as -1(got by using `$?`), when i tried using `$!` it says `No child processes`.

I'm executing this script by using `sudo` command

```
sudo -u <uname> bash
<script_name>.pl
```

This Perl script is working fine if i execute it directly from my user id. I really don't understand why this error shows up only when i execute through sudo user.

Please help me to understand this error.

EDIT:It's working fine if i give `$SIG{CHLD} = 'DEFAULT';` in my code. But, if i remove this step, the problem shows up again. I got this code from WWW when i was browsing about this error. Any idea what it does?

Comment: It's very difficult to diagnose this without seeing at least the relevant parts of your perl code.

Comment: Its a 300 lines of code and i really don't know in which part of the code this error arises.

Comment: The [perl documentation for `wait()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html) may help.

Comment: $! is altered for errors in the current process.

Comment: @Horus Can you please provide more detail on what you said?

Comment: What I mean is, he is running a child process, and appears to want that error information. The $! variable only stores error information for the current process, it will never store information for the child process.  The SQLLDR error information can be collected into the current process a number of ways, but not with $!.

Comment: I know you mentioned your code is over 300 lines but it would be helpful if you could provide the part of the code around the '$!' part. Can you please provide at least a few lines before and including the line where you are printing or dying with $!? It would be most helpful, but maybe not enough, we won't know until we see it.

Comment: I've seen this error before... you're setting $SIG{CHLD} to 'IGNORE' in this script or setting it as such in a parent process.  The problem is that `system` uses `waitpid` (or a form of it) to wait for your command to complete.  If you're ignoring child process terminations, then `waitpid` will try to reap a child already disappeared.  Using wait when you have no child processes gives this error.

Answer (score 1):

On most Unix platforms, the `CHLD` (sometimes also known as `CLD`) signal has special behavior with respect to a value of `'IGNORE'`. Setting `$SIG{CHLD}` to `'IGNORE'` on such a platform has the effect of not creating zombie processes when the parent process fails to `wait()` on its child processes (i.e. child processes are automatically reaped). Calling `wait()` with `$SIG{CHLD}` set to `'IGNORE'` usually returns `-1` on such platforms.
*Excerpted from http://perl.active-venture.com/pod/perlipc-signal.html*

Basically what is happening is that somewhere the `CHLD` signal has been set to `IGNORE` *probably by sqlldr*. When you attempt to check on the status of the child process you receive the `-1` which is sometimes referred to as `ECHILD`. This occurs because the information about the completion status of the child process has been discarded due to the ignoring of the `CHLD` signal. By setting `$SIG{CHLD} = 'DEFAULT';` you are indicating that the CHLD signal should be handled by the DEFAULT handler and not ignored.

I do not know why the `CHLD` signal is being ignored when the script is executed from sudo user versus being executed directly from your user id.